# product catalog and Einstein email recommendation

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations

Can someone please explain me what is the use of product catalog in Einstein email recommendations

Thanks In Advance,
Nikhila

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The catalog functionality is used for multiple purposes within Einstein Recommendations. Here are the major areas to consider when consulting on what fields to add to a catalog:

- Support Collect: The catalog data passed via Collect ties to the
  catalog in the data via the Product Code (item) and SkuID
  (unique_id). These fields must match the Collect data to ensure
  proper function.
- Build User Profiles: When collecting user-data, the
  catalog takes the view ID and uses the tagged fields to build the
  profile.
- Support Recommendation Generation: Any data from the catalog
  can be used to build the recommendation. The catalog is the only
  access to the metadata used to produce recommendations.
- Locale and Language Support: If any attributes vary by a locale or
  language, add the field to the catalog.
- Support Attribute-Based Rules: Data that is in the catalog can support
  rule generation. For example, if you want only Men’s clothes shown in a
  particular recommendation, a field like “gender” could support this rule.
  If a data type is not in the catalog, rules cannot be generated for it.

Marketing Cloud accepts three types of catalogs:

- Product: Products available for purchase
- Content: Articles, blogs posts, videos, or other types of content available for view
- Banner: Image files such as hero graphics, calls to action, or offers

You can import one file for each catalog type.

[Source](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_pb_catalog.htm&type=5)